# Совместная разработка с ограниченным доступом по фтп

Tags: git, gitlab

К разработке проекта на php нужно подключить несколько фронтендеров и php-программистов, но есть обязательное условие ограничение для них полного доступа ко всем папкам проекта. Есть репозиторий gitlab с одной основной веткой и ее дочерной веткой для этих разработчиков. Соответственно два хоста, для основной ветки репозитория и для дочерной. На хосте дочерной ветки репозитория для разработчиков можно создавать фтп-аккаунты к отдельным папкам с файлами в которых они будут работать. Как можно организовать такую совместную их работу при условии то что, например, фронтендерам нужно будет редактировать одинаковые файлы? Отдельные ветки репозитория с работой на локалхосте получается невозможно при таких условиях организовать каждому из разработчиков.

Comment: Что-то либо я чего-то не понимаю, либо вы. Зачем FTP, при наличии Git? Это прям-таки придумывание проблемы на ровном месте, что-бы потом её героически преодолевать.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае каждый разработчик должен вести работу в своей отдельной среде. Свои коммиты отправляет в репозиторий, где они мерджатся в тестовую или основную ветку. Потом эта ветка выливается на тестовый сервер.